# are moduli stacks deligne-mumford stacks in general

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, moduli-spaces, stacks

Let M be your favorite moduli stack over the field of complex numbers.

Is it reasonable to expect M to be a Deligne-Mumford stack?

I know this is true for the moduli space of curves of genus g, ppav's and K3 surfaces. I'm just wondering what I should expect when considering other moduli stacks.

Comment: Stable coherent sheaves are simple and so have a $\mathbb{G}_{m}$ of automorphisms.

Comment: My favorite is $Vect_{n,d}(C)$ of vector bundles on a curve of genus $g\geq 2$ of fixed rank and degree up to isomorphism. The automorphism group has positive dimension, hence not a Deligne-Mumford stack. Maybe what you should expect is to replace Deligne-Mumford by Artin.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it has no real answer. Or maybe the answer is "it depends on your taste", and on the meaning of "favorite".

Comment: The problem is, one can define a moduli stack (which is Artin) for any groupoid in the category of complex manifolds. Generically these won't be étale, hence the stack won't be Deligne-Mumford.

Comment: Why voting to close? The question has a simple answer: 'no'.

Comment: As a side remark, this provides motivation for using the smooth topology over the etale topology since in the etale topology you will only have finite fibers. This means that given a presentation of an algebraic stack (meaning by etale morphisms), it will only have finite fibers, while taking a presentation of a stack in the smooth topology means you have have non-zero dimension fibers translating to non-zero dimensional stabilizers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the objects under consideration all have finite automorphism groups, you should expect your stack to be Deligne-Mumford.  Otherwise, it isn't Deligne-Mumford; but that is no cause for alarm.

Comment: It would be a bit more accurate to say "finite etale automorphism schemes" (though since offered just as an "expectation", perhaps one cannot insist on too much precision).

Comment: As nosr points out, this answer is incorrect.  For a very natural example, the stacks of Kontsevich stable maps are not (usually) Deligne-Mumford in positive characteristic.

Comment: @Jason: For another example, $X_0(N)$ (appropriately defined as a proper flat Artin stack over $\mathbf{Z}$) is not Deligne-Mumford in characteristic $p$ when $p^2|N$.

Comment: Correction: As userN points out, I missed the OP's hypothesis that the stack is defined over $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{C})$.  For stacks over $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{C})$, I agree with Ravi: every algebraic stack with finite diagonal is Deligne-Mumford.  This follows from Artin's theorems.

Answer (score 7):

No (per the many examples in the comments).

Comment: The question specifies 'over the complex numbers', which rules out all of the examples listed so far.  I think Ravi's right that we should expect DM in the case of complex algebraic objects with finite automorphism groups.